# Working on an inequality

Tags: calculus, inequality

Hey all I am trying to show that an inequality involving integrals is true, and I am not sure if I am taking the right approach or what I am missing.

I will write one of the inequalities I am trying to show and il put the work and my ideas so far.

Show that for any $n \in \mathbb z^{+} $, and any real $q \ge 0 $, the following inequality holds,

$\int_0^n x^qdx$ $\le 1 + 2^{q}+ 3^{q}+…+n^{q}$ $\le \int_0^{n+1}x^qdx$

I am thinking that I will need to show this by cases,

Ie, for q=0 we would have  $n \le n \le n+1$ so it holds

for $0 \lt q \lt 1$, I am having trouble figuring out what I should do,

for q=1, i used that $\sum1+2+3..+n$ = $n(n+1)/2$ which worked to show that as well,

and for q>1 I am unsure again.

So basically I am having issues with those two conditions, and am also not sure if what I already did with the other cases is correct. I am open to any answers, hints, suggestions and comments. Thanks all

Comment: Do you know about upper and lower sums?

Comment: Yes , not in huge amount of detail but enough that we have learned about them.

Comment: I didn't just ask a random question. It was a hint.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The idea is simple :

$$\int_0^n x^q dx = \sum_{k=1}^{n} \int_{k-1}^k x^q dx \leq \sum_{k=1}^{n} \int_{k-1}^k k^q dx  $$

Then

$$\int_0^n x^q dx \leq \sum_{k=1}^{n} k^q  = 1+ 2^q + \cdots n^q $$

And for the other inequality,

$$\int_0^{n+1} x^q dx = \sum_{k=0}^{n} \int_{k}^{k+1} x^q dx \geq \sum_{k=0}^{n} \int_{k}^{k+1} k^q dx  $$

Then

$$\int_0^{n+1} x^q dx \geq \sum_{k=0}^{n} k^q  = 1+ 2^q + \cdots n^q $$

Comment: Thanks this seems good, I have a few question. In the first part, how can you conclude that your integral x^q is less then the sum of integral from k-1 to k of k^q?

Comment: Because the function $x\mapsto x^q$ is increasing on $[k-1,k]$, then we have for all $x$ in $[k-1,k],  x^q \leq k^q$

Comment: Ah I see and just to be clear this is for 0<q<1?

Comment: This is for $q \geq 0$

Comment: I mean the first part you showed compared to the second?

Comment: Or is q greater or equal to 0 all one case?

Comment: All one case here, as we only use the fact that x^q is increasing.

Answer (score 0):

Consider these two graphs, they could help:

[image]

[image]